# psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, scrapy, psycopg2

I Wrote a scrapy program to scrape data from a site, the program does scrape successfully if I am scraping to a json file or csv file, the issue arises when I try to scrape into my postgres database, the below picture shows the error I receive, How can I fix the error:

[image]

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    """Save deals in the database.
    This method is called for every item pipeline component.
    """
    self.cur.execute("insert into Deals (Name,Deal_Url,Image_Url,Old_Price,Special_Price,Final_Price) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(item['Name'],item['Product_URL'],item['Image_URL'],item['Old_Price'],item['Special_Price'],item['Final_Price']))
    self.connection.commit()
    return item
```

Answer (score 32):

When an operation fails in a transaction you need to rollback, besides fixing the malicious operation (could be trying to access any value in `item` that doesn't exist) you could wrap your insert statement in a try/except block:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    """Save deals in the database.
    This method is called for every item pipeline component.
    """

    try:
        self.cur.execute("insert into Deals (Name,Deal_Url,Image_Url,Old_Price,Special_Price,Final_Price) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(item['Name'],item['Product_URL'],item['Image_URL'],item['Old_Price'],item['Special_Price'],item['Final_Price']))
        self.connection.commit()
    except:
        self.connection.rollback()
    return item
```

Comment: How can I handle some values that null? No data is being inserted to my Database, I think its the null values causing the errors

Comment: You could use default values, instead of `item['Name']` use `item.get('Name', None)`