# Postgresql / Psycopg2 issue while scraping -

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I ran into an issue with my scraper and I am at a loss and need you help here.

I scrape data from [www.racingpost.com](http://www.racingpost.com) and store the data in a Postgresql database (using pgadmin4 to organize it) and psycopg2 for the connection

**This worked perfectly fine until yesterday**, where I wanted to scrape some newer data.

I collect the links to the sites with one spider, save them in a json, read the json with the second spider and crawl these links. I log the errors so I can see where a problem might be.

Now, if I run the spider, the second spider does not crawl all the links in the json properly.
The code is exactly the same as before, and is **not** the issue and it seems the behavior of psycopg2 has changed.

After the first error:

```
    ERROR:scrapy.core.scraper:Error processing {'date': ('16.03.2022',), 'track': ('Chantilly (FR)',), 'racename': ('Prix des Ecuries Cantiliennes (Handicap) (4yo+) (All-Weather Track) (Polytrack)',), 'racetype': ('Flat',), 'distance': (1911.1,), 'group': ('',), 'raceclass': (0,), 'classrating': (0,), 'alterteilnehmer': ('4yo+',), 'starterzahl': (13,), 'minalter': (4,), 'maxalter': (99,), 'winningtime': (0,), 'going': ('Standard',), 'finalhurdle': (0,), 'omitted': (0,), 'pricemoney1': (9319.0,), 'pricemoney2': (3727.0,), 'pricemoney3': (2796.0,), 'pricemoney4': (1863.0,), 'pricemoney5': (932.0,), 'pricemoney6': (0.0,), 'pricemoney7': (0.0,), 'pricemoney8': (0.0,), 'racetime': ('3:45',)}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 857, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 162, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\****\projects\jsontest\jsontest\pipelines.py", line 30, in process_item
    self.store_db(item)
  File "C:\Users\****\projects\jsontest\jsontest\pipelines.py", line 64, in store_db
    self.cur.execute("insert into races(racedate, track, racename, racetype, distancefinal, gruppe, raceclass, classrating, alterteilnehmer, starterzahl, minalter, maxalter, winningtime, going, finalhurdle, omitted, pricemoney1, pricemoney2, pricemoney3, pricemoney4, pricemoney5, pricemoney6, pricemoney7, pricemoney8, racetime) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: FEHLER:  aktuelle Transaktion wurde abgebrochen, Befehle werden bis zum Ende der Transaktion ignoriert
```

**every other** crawled result from here on will result in an error message like this.

This was not the case before, where the next transaction (the next result) was processed normaly. And if I crawl these "error" results with the same spider, but without reading the json file (so only this one result) everything works fine.
And as I said - this code just read 165000 sites woithout a single error three days ago.

So I guess the problem is *not the code per se* - what could prompt such problems in psycopg2?

- Any known issues I missed by googling?
- How can I narrow it down?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Well, you've clearly had an SQL error that isn't getting cleared.  Is `date` literally a date/time field?  That's not a date format Postgres understands.  Are any of your fields required to be unique?

Comment: The `psycopg2` error: `ERROR: current transaction aborted, commands are ignored until the end of the transaction` is a side effect of the `scrapy` error: `ERROR:scrapy.core.scraper:Error processing`. You need to figure out why `scrapy` choked on that data.

Comment: Allright, then scrapy is the culprit. Any idea why crapy chokes on this data when I let scrapy crawl over multiple links from the json, but if I let it crawl a single link it works? Oh, and what could be the reason for every link after the first error become an error too?

Comment: Not sure why `scrapy` is not working with the one link, you will have to dig more into what is being returned from the link. As to the second question that is due to the error: `ERROR: current transaction aborted, commands are ignored until the end of the transaction`.  Once that error happens every thing else will fail. You need use a `try/except` to catch the exception(error) and deal with it so you can continue with the rest of the links.

Comment: I just don't get it - the links are there - and they work if I single feed them to scrapy. But if they are passed in a crawler, scrapy produces errors - and I can't find the reason. I made a try / expect statement in my pipline (just except: print('An Error')) - but with thes same result. As soon as scrapy chokes on the first link and the first error pops up, everything after this results in an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65132944/psycopg2-errors-infailedsqltransaction-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands)